# Is this grammar LL(1) grammar?

Tags: formal-grammars

Is this grammar LL(1)? Would it be a problem that S can be both E/S and E?

```
S -> E / S 
S -> E
E -> letter 
E -> ‘ S ’
```

Can it derive ‘a / e / ‘g / s’ ’ / q like this?

```
S - >  E / S 
S - > ‘S’ / S 
S - > ‘E / S’ / S 
S - > ‘a / S’/ S
S - > ‘a / E / S’ / S
S - > ‘a / E / ‘E / S’’ / S
S - > ‘a / e / ‘g / s’’ / q
```

Answer (score 1):

Plugging it into my [LL(1) computer, loner](https://benknoble.github.io/loner/demo.html) gives false:

```
<S> ::= <E> | <S>;
<S> ::= <E>;
<E> ::= 'letter';
<E> ::= '"' <S> '"';
```

(Note there are some duplicate rules here, which become apparent in the formatted version.)

Proving it (e.g., via the set properties or a pumping lemma) is left an exercise.

---

If `/` is intended to a be terminal (and not alternation!), then we have

```
<S> ::= <E> '/' <S>;
<S> ::= <E>;
<E> ::= 'letter';
<E> ::= '"' <S> '"';
```

is still not LL(1).

---

The derivation would be more readable (and more obviously correct) if shown like (e.g.)

```
S ->  E / S
(with E -> 'S')
-> 'S' / S
(with S -> E / S)
-> 'E / S' / S
(with E -> letter)
-> 'a / S'/ S
(with S -> E / S)
-> 'a / E / S' / S
(with S -> E -> 'S' -> 'E / S') ; note the application of several steps, here
-> 'a / E / 'E / S'' / S
(with S -> E -> letter) ; and again. better to be explicit
-> 'a / e / 'g / s'' / q
```